# Characters broken in React Native with Arabic and Persian Language on Android axios (XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: android, encoding, react-native, xmlhttprequest, axios

Is there anyone has this problem?

With Arabic and Persian language,

I am using axios. And axios using XmlHttpRequest on react-native.
There is no problem with iphone.
But on android, The characters are broken. Not only those Arabic or Persian language but also other all JSON parsed data characters.
I am using application/json for request, response.
But I can see correct data on iphone and web.
Only on android react native.

What is the problem??

Do I have to process something on the server??

Is it because some ambiguous character ? Like RTL or some special charater code in Arabic or Persian language??

I can't find the reason....

Anyone could help me?

Comment: you only get this error in your client-server communication?

Comment: Yes. I guess react native android XMLHttpRequest module's application/json parsing on arabic and persian language has some bug.

Comment: import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';
window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;

It makes error!!!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with French accents.

Comment: Did somebody find solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

What we found out that when typing Arabic rn fetch blob thinks that text is invalid utf8. That is why it tries to send it as base64. So, in response you need to parse base64 text using Buffer or pako.